# Spring Boot with Hibernate Update Corresponding Columns

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Please I need some Spring Boot with Hibernate assistance.
I have 2 tables called
1. Student info
2. School fees

The Student info table has entities like Student ID as primary key, name, School fee.
The  School fees table is supposed to have entities like student id as a foreign key, tuition, books, medicals, transport, e.t.c, and summing their values is supposed to equal the School Fee entity value on the Student info table for that student id.

Please how do I use hibernate to programmatically achieve this...... So that once i save a student's info it automatically creates/updates the corresponding student id column of the School fee table

Comment: There are plenty of examples over internet. Kindly do bit research and ask questions if you stuck at any place. Reference link https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/spring-boot-crud-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

I think using Hibernate for this purpose is the wrong tool. 
Hibernate isn't an engine for arbitrary database operations.
And more specific Hibernate delays writes and caches reads so relying on something to happen during write is asking for trouble since you will keep seeing the old state until you start a new session or do some Hibernate trickery.

Instead I recommend to take a sip from the Domain Driven Design Bottle.
Consider your `StudentInfo` entity an aggregate root, with methods to manipulate the different fees. These methods then set the value and create or update the `SchoolFee` entity.